# read sms permission using expo cli - REACT NATIVE

Tags: react-native, android-permissions, expo

I could not find permission for READ_SMS
https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/permissions/

Wanted to know how can I request permission for READ_SMS using expo-cli
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have researched and there isn't support for read sms using expo, so, if you want this feature, you need eject expo